# How to Append Textbox value to Datatable column value?

Tags: c#, datatable

Here my webpage contains uploadbutton and textbox. When I upload one Excel File it contains Name and Contacts it stores in Datatable after I enter any integer value in Textbox the textbox value will be append to all fields of contacts column in Datatable.
Here I am write some code but it shows actual DATAtable Data.textbox value will not append to it..

```
public void  countrycode(DataTable dt,string colname,string str)
{

foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        str += i;            
    }
    dt.AcceptChanges();
}

}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. The code that you've tried just creates new local strings by looping the columns in the table which is pretty pointless.

Comment: when i enter any value in textbox the textbox value will be append to Datatable  contacts values

Comment: So you have _one_ column `Contacts` and you want to replace the value in that field of each row by adding `str` to the end?

Comment: contacts :9988995599 when i enter 91 in textbox the 9988995599 value should be replaced with 919988995599

Comment: So you don't want to append it(add to the end) but prepend it(before)?

Comment: exactly sir..i want to append it (before)

Comment: So you don't want to append but prepend it. Have a look at my edited answer below.

Comment: Tim Schmelter:in this example how can i find whether Contacts columns values already having Textbox value or NOT?

Comment: You could use `row[columnName].ToString().StartsWith(str)`.

Comment: stackover flow doesnt provide More than one acceptance Button.otherwise i will check.....Thankyou So Much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have *one* column `Contacts` and you want to replace the value in that field of each row by adding `str` to the end you have to **loop the rows not the columns**:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    row.SetField("Contacts", row.Field<string>("Contacts") + str);
}
```

If the column name is dynamic and you actually don't want to append but  to prepend it as suggested by your comments use this code:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    row.SetField(columnName, str + row.Field<string>(columnName));
}
```

If you can't use [`DataRowExtensions.Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.field%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can also use the indexer:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    row[columnName] = row.IsNull(columnName) ? str : str + row[columnName].ToString();
}
```

Comment: here i have two columns Name and Contacts

Comment: @Raamraj: and you also want to change the `Name` field? If the column name is dynamic replace `"Contacts"` with the variable name, for example `colname`.

Comment: System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'Field' and the best extension method overload 'System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field<T>(System.Data.DataRow, string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @Raamraj: what framework are you using? [`DataRowExtensions.Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.field%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an extension method for `DataRow`. To use it you have to use at least .NET 3.5 and you have to add a reference to the  System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll. I've edited the answer again to provide an alternative.